# Magento - wordpress Fishpig integration error [function.is-writable]

Tags: wordpress, magento, integration, blogs, fishpig

i have problem with integrating Wordpress and Magento.
After inserting the blog route in the Fishpig Magento plugin, Wordpress displays these errors:

on line 132:

`Warning: is_writable() [function.is-writable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/data/web/virtuals/27914/virtual) in /data/web/virtuals/27914/virtual/www/wp./wp-admin/options-permalink.php`

on line 133:

```
Warning: is_writable() [function.is-writable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/data/web/virtuals/27914/virtual) in /data/web/virtuals/27914/virtual/www/wp./wp-admin/includes/misc.php
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I had a bit of a fight this week with the Fishpig module and Magento - are you using the latest version of the module? What do you mean by 'error in permalinks?' - are your blog pages 404s all the time?

Answer (score 1):

These errors are happening in the WordPress Admin itself, of which the WordPress Integration extension has no control over (none of the extensions is executed in the WP Admin). These errors are caused by your server restrictions (open_basedir) and are caused - I believe - when WordPress tries to write to your .htaccess file.

These errors can be ignored and will go away when you refresh the page. That being said, to fix them, you will need to contact your hosting company or server administrator.